# Hide menu items for users with custom role

Tags: directus

I have a custom role for "regular users". for those users I would like to hide / remove some of the menu items in the lower left corner:

[image]

basically all I want them to be able to do is to edit their profile, or to sign out. — I was wondering if and how that's possible.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a way to do this out-of-the-box now without you changing the core codebase. I've added a Feature Request to the Directus App repo:

https://github.com/directus/app/issues/1709

Give it a thumbs up and we'll try to include it soon!

Good idea!